# Nikon 18-200mm lens work with either of these d90, d3100 or d5000?

Tags: lens, nikon-d90, nikon-d3100, nikon-d5000

I am new to DSLR cameras and i have been doing some research on them from last few days and then i wanted to go for one of these model bodies: D90, D5000 or D3100 and i want to purchase the following lens for the dslr camera.

**Nikon 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6 G ED-IF AF-S VR DX Zoom-Nikkor Lens**

I want to purchase them separately and i am not sure if this lens works with any of the above cameras. My question is whether the this lens will works with any of the above models, if the answer is NO which camera works well with this lens. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

That's a newer-technology (AF-S) lens and newer cameras, so they're all compatible.

[Ninon SLR Camera to Lens Compatibility](http://www.nikonians.org/nikon/slr-lens.html).

The lens will work "well" on any of those cameras. They all have the same sensor size (DX), so you'll get the same field of view / effective focal length. Which is the "best" camera for you will depend mostly on other factors.

Nikon is very good about lens compatibility; they've been using the same mount since 1959. Occasionally, on some esoteric combinations of camera/lens, you'll lose some features like autofocus or manual aperture control, but it's uncommon, easy to check in advance, and reasonably simple to work around.

Comment: What do you mean, "non-D40"? I'm fairly sure this lens would work with the D40. In fact, I believe the D40 was the first to drop the internal AF motor and rely entirely on AF-S.

Comment: @Evan Krall: by that I meant that the D40 will not work fully with certain lenses; it won't AF on non-AF-S lenses. As it happens, the D3100 and D5000 also have the same issue, so I'm going to pull the D40 bit from my answer; it's just confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work with any of this cameras.

In more details - Nikon AF lenses will only autofocus with cameras with in body motor, because there is no motor inside lens. Among cameras you mentioned only D90 has such motor. AF-S lenses have motor inside them, and body just controls this motor - any of cameras you mentioned will autofocus with such lenses.

Also note that AF lenses can be mounted on D3100 and D5000 - you can use them if you dont mind focusing manually.